# Extjs GridPanel selections from database

Tags: extjs, gridpanel

My idea is to have a combobox filled with sectors, and a list of users below with checkboxes to indicate if each user belongs to the selected sector.

The sectors are stored in my database and each user can have their id linked to one or more sectors.

I know how to fill the combo with the sectors, and the grid with the users, but how can I make a checkbox for each user which changes depending on the sector selected?

And then, could I update those selections to my database?

I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: You should add more irrelevant tags to your question, and remove all the code and links which show what you have found and tried. *sarcasm*

Comment: I'm sorry if it's not the proper way to ask, it's actually the first question I post in this site. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion. Will do.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can give id to your checkboxes like this: "chk_USR001" (i assume your users's have an unique id like "USR001").
And when combobox selection change, go to server and get the users in selected sector and select the right checkboxes (using item id) while looping.
if you share some code snippets, we could help more.
regards.